# Removing eyesores near eyes

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Removing ngons didn't help and I couldn't remove both triangles and ngons. How can I remove the eyesores near the eyes of my model?

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Use proper topology while modelling, blindly removing ngons and triangles will do you no good alone, you need proper edge flow. That model has terrible topology see http://topologyguides.com/ for good practices.

Comment: Avoid triangles, avoid ngons, keep your mesh with quads. Around the eyes you need loops. Look online for topology guides for faces and eyes in particular

Comment: Yes, the topology is terrible. That's because I made the head first and the eyelids separately, to use minimal geometry to be time-efficient. I will retopologise the head model later and see if that helps.